# How to get pegged testnet tokens?

Tags: blockchain, tokens, wrapped-tokens

I want to get FUSDC/FUDST on fantom Testnet or USDT/USDC on Avalanche Testnet. The obvious problem is all the faucet only provides native tokens, not the pegged tokens. Is there a way to get pegged tokens for testing?

Answer (score -1):

Swap the testnet FTM for testnet USDC, or anything else.